# How to get the value of a content type field in Drupal and pass it to a JS file

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7, soundcloud

In my Drupal theme I have a field for soundCloud URL which its machine name is (field_soundcloud_url_) I have a javascript file that will work based of the value of this variable. But it does not work. Here is how I tried to do it:

**page.tpl.php**

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $sound_cloud_url = $node->field_soundcloud_url_['und'][0]['value'];
  drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('sound_cloud_url' => $sound_cloud_url)), 'setting');
?>
```

**JS File**

```
Drupal.settings.my_module.sound_cloud_url
```

Am I doing it correctly? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because you are doing it in the template, it is too late by this stage.
Do it in a [HOOK_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) in a custom module.

```
function HOOK_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type=="blahblah"){
    $sound_cloud_url = $node->field_soundcloud_url_['und'][0]['value'];
    drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('sound_cloud_url' => $sound_cloud_url)), 'setting');
  }
}
```